# What does -> do in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have seen the clojure symbol -> used in many places, but I am unsure as to what this symbol is called and does, or even whether it is part of standard clojure. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

-> uses the result of a function call and send it, in sequence, to the next function call.

So, the easier example would be:

```
 (-> 2 (+ 3))
```

Returns 5, because it sends 2, to the next function call (+ 3)

Building up on this,

```
(-> 2 
  (+ 3) 
  (- 7))
```

Returns -2. We keep the result of the first call, (+ 3) and send it to the second call (- 7).

As noted by @bending, the accepted answer would have been better showing the doto macro.

```
(doto person
  (.setFName "Joe")
  (.setLName "Bob")
  (.setHeight [6 2]))
```

Comment: this is inaccurate.  2 does not get sent to a function call of `(+ 3)`...  Instead a macro rearranges the code from say `(-> a b c)` to `(c (b a))`

Comment: mostly playing with words, but i do accept the criticism. thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @nicolas I've been meaning to update my answer since the day I submitted it because it was confusing, but the website wouldn't let me. I made a long overdue update to the answer. If it's still misleading let me know.

Answer (score 16):

It's a way to write code left to right, instead of inside out, e.g.

```
(reduce (map (map xs bar) foo) baz)
```

becomes

```
(-> xs (map bar) (map foo) (reduce baz))
```

You might want to read the source, it's [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L1482).

EDIT: Fixed my confusion of `->` with `->>`, thanks to amalloy. Sadly my example is now quite unlikely to appear in practice.

Comment: I like this explanation of the thrush operator in Clojure best: http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2010/04/thrush-in-clojure.html

Comment: This is right in generalities, but wrong on specifics. You've described the behavior of `->>`, not `->`. Your provided sample would expand to `(reduce (map (map xs bar) foo) baz)`, because `->` threads through the *second* position, not the *last* (which is what `->>` does).

Comment: I'm sorry, I will fix my answer.

Comment: @amalloy Damn Clojure; third answer and the respondent is again wrong on something! :-)

Answer (score 15):

I did not fully get what  -> (thrush or thread) did until I visualized it like this:

```
(-> expr f1 f2 f3)  ;same as (f3 (f2 (f1 expr)))

(-> expr            ;same as form above
    f1              ;just a different visual layout
    f2
    f3)

;this form is equivalant and shows the lists for f1, f2, f3.
(->         expr     ; expr treaded into first form
        (f1     )    ;  |   result threaded into next form
    (f2          )   ;  |   and so on...
(f3               )) ;  V   the lists (f1

(f3 (f2 (f1 expr)))  ;the result is the same as this
```

Here are some examples:

```
(-> 41 inc dec inc)   ;same as (inc (dec (inc 41)))
42

(->            41     ;same as above but more readable
          (inc   )
     (dec         )
(inc               ))
42

(inc (dec (inc 41)))  ;easier to see equivalence with above form.
42

(-> 4 (* 4 3) (- 6))  ;same as (- (* 4 3 4) 6)
42 

(->   4               ;      4
   (*   3 4)          ;   (* 4 3 4)
(-           6))      ;(- (* 4 3 4) 6)
42

(- (* 4 3 4) 6)       ;easier to see equivalence with above form.
42
```

Comment: hey, I have query with your explanation, you wrote

`(-> expr f1 f2 f3)  ;same as (f3 (f2 (f1 expr)))`

but 
`(->  2  (+ 3) ( - 7)) ` is not equal to `( - 7 (+ 3 2))`
result of first one is `-2` but second one is `2`

can you help me what i am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 9):

'->' is a macro. The best way to describe it, I think, is in the example of the "dot special form" for which it serves the purpose of making the code more terse and legible as is indicated on the clojure.org website's explanation of the [The Dot special form](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-The%20Dot%20special%20form-%28..%20Classname-symbol%20member+%29)

```
(.. System (getProperties) (get "os.name"))
```

expands to:

```
(. (. System (getProperties)) (get "os.name"))
```

but is easier to write, read, and understand. See also the -> macro which can be used similarly:

```
(-> (System/getProperties) (.get "os.name"))
```

There is also 'doto'. Let's say you have a single object on which you'd like to call several consecutive setters. You could use 'doto'.

```
(doto person
  (.setFName "Joe")
  (.setLName "Bob")
  (.setHeight [6 2]))
```

In the above example the setters don't return anything, making 'doto' the appropriate choice. The -> would not work in place of 'doto' unless the setters returned 'this'.

So, those are some techniques related to the -> macro. I hope that helps explain not only what they do, but also why they exist.

Comment: Your setters all return this? If not, then you'll want to be using (doto ...)

Answer (score 3):

You can see for yourself:

```
(macroexpand `(-> 42 inc dec))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called the thrush operator. It's best explained [here](http://www.viksit.com/node/33).

Comment: This is not true. Thrush is a *function* that behaves similarly to `->`. `->` and `->>` are macros, and I usually hear them referred to as "threading" macros, because they "thread" the first form through the rest to result in one stitched-together form.