# What does the leading arrow in a name mean in clojure

Tags: clojure

Learning Clojure I came across code like below:

```
=> (defrecord Person [name, age])
user.Person
=> (->Person "john" 40)
#user.Person{:name "john", :age 40}
=> (Person. "tom" 30)
#user.Person{:name "tom", :age 30}
```

the question is, what does the leading arrow(i.e., ***->***) in the ***->Person*** mean ? It's a reader macro or what ? I see no description of it in the reader section of clojuredoc. Further, what is the difference between ***->Person*** and ***Person.*** ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It has no syntactic meaning.  It is just part of the symbol name.  In Lisps, the arrow `->` (or even just '>') is often used to imply conversion of, or casting of, one type into another.  In the macro expansion of the `defrecord`:

```
(macroexpand '(defrecord Person [name age]))
```

you can see that it defines `->Person` as a function that calls the `Person` constructor.  `->Person` (the function) may be more convenient for you to use than `Person.` (the direct call to the Java constructor) as you can pass it as an argument to other functions, capture it in a variable and use it, etc:

```
(let [f ->Person]
  (f "Bob" 65))
```

Compare that to:

```
(let [f Person.]
  (f "Bob" 65))
```

Which is syntactically invalid.

Comment: Your mentioned background of arrow from lisp makes it more easier to understand. Sometime a piece of background helps readers a lot more than piles of technical description. Thanks

Comment: How would one use `map->Person`?

Comment: The "x->y" comes from a Scheme naming convention.  Think of it as shorthand for "converted to".

http://www.scheme.com/tspl2d/intro.html

"The names of procedures that convert an object of one type into an object of another type are written as type1->type2, e.g., vector->list."

Answer (score 5):

Obviously not in your specific example, but in the general context this operator `->` is called the [threading operator](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E) and is considered one of the thrush operators. Along with its cousin the `->>` operator, these operators are quite useful when you need to have code appear more clearly, especially when feeding the output of functions as parameters to another function. Both operators are macros. Here's another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4579226/what-does-do-in-clojure) concerning both operators.

I have not yet had cause to use the `->`, but did need `->>` to make sense of code that needed to compute intermediate values and put them all into one function call.

Here is another [explanation](http://www.viksit.com/node/33).