# How can I convert a vector to a record?

Tags: clojure

For example, if I had:

```
(defrecord Item [name cost])
```

How could I convert `["ball" 10]` to `{:name "ball", :cost 10}`?

Comment: want to convert it into Json like {key:value} pair format?

Comment: I think as long as it's a hash map, it'll be fine.  I mean, that's basically what a record is, right?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
user=> (defrecord Item [name cost])
user=> (apply ->Item ["ball" 10])
#user.Item{:name "ball", :cost 10}
```

Short explain of what's going on. `(->Item "ball" 10)` is one of syntax for creating record from given arguments. It's the same as `(Item. "ball" 10)`. In your case you have vector of arguments, so we use `(apply fn args-vector)` to deal with.

Comment: Kudos if you could expand on where the ->Item function comes from

Comment: Alexey you've been teaching me Clojure all day!  Thank you (again).  Can you quickly tell me what the `->` is called so I can research it's meaning further?

Comment: Added short explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Relevant quote from the `defrecord` docs, perhaps could be added to the answer as per @ArthurUlfeldt suggestion: "Given `(defrecord TypeName ...)`, two factory functions will be
defined: `->TypeName`, taking positional parameters for the fields,
and `map->TypeName`, taking a map of keywords to field values."

Comment: @Inlinevoid, you may like to see [the detailed explanation of the leading ***->***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12048151/what-does-the-leading-arrow-in-a-name-mean-in-clojure)